# Task.WaitAny when there are multiple tasks that finishes at the same time

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I'm using Task.WaitAny and passing in the array of tasks that are running. I would like to know how I can capture all the completed tasks' indexes, if there were multiple tasks that completes at the same time.

For instance, I'm retrieving the index of the task that completes as follows:`

```
int i = Task.WaitAny(taskArray);
```

Using the index i, I'm replacing that position in the array with another launched task. The taskArray has a fixed length and I can only launch new tasks and replace tasks in the array as they complete. How can I do this if I only get one index returned on the Task.WaitAny() and it's possible that multiple tasks within the array may complete at the same time. If only one index is returned, how do I handle other tasks that completes at the same time?

`

Comment: Can you use Task.WaitAll ?

Comment: I think I tried this, but this method doesn't return until all tasks within the array has completed. I would like to retrieve the index of the tasks as they complete and not wait until all of them completes.

Comment: Maybe you can put the code in the Task itself, (a delegate, for example) that can notify the other function that it finished, then for example update the User Interface with the completed tasks.

Comment: I was hoping to use the Wait to block the parent thread from continuing until at least one of the tasks complete. If I use a callback function in which the child task calls back to the parent thread, I'll have to make the task array a member variable. I will try this method if there's not an easier way.

Answer (score 6):

> If only one index is returned, how do I handle other tasks that completes at the same time?

To be clear: it is for all intents and purposes impossible that it could literally be true that more than one task would complete *at the same time*. Even running in separate CPU cores concurrently, the likelihood of true simultaneous completion is basically nil.

So, what you are really asking about is the race condition where one task completes, and then before your call to `WaitAny()` returns in your thread and the subsequent code in the calling method can execute, one or more other tasks also complete.

Your question lacks detail regarding your actual scenario, but typically you've got a couple of options:

1. Scan the `taskArray` you passed to `WaitAny()` to look for all of the currently completed tasks.
2. Call `WaitAny()` again, with all of the previously passed tasks except the one you know about.

Which is more appropriate depends on what you actually need to do with the completion information. The first option is best in cases where you only care about the currently completed tasks and want to deal with them right away. The second option is best in cases where you are interested in ordered completion result (i.e. to know which task completed in which order), but do also want to immediately continue waiting for the remainder.

Note that in the second option, if more than one task is completed before you get to call `WaitAny()` again, the ordering is somewhat arbitrary due to the race condition. The condition is "solved" by the `WaitAny()` method, with it choosing which task is presented to you as the current task that has just completed. But unless you maintain your own timing information in each task, you won't be able to know for sure which truly completed first.

If the above does not adequately address your concern, you need to improve your question, so that it includes complete details as to why the above doesn't address your concern, and exactly how you are trying to use the completion of the `WaitAny()` method. Make sure you include a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates all of this.

*(Aside: the above all of course ignores whether one should use `WaitAny()` at all. It would generally be better to asynchronously wait using `WhenAny()`. But the same basic issues apply, and would not change the answer, so it seems reasonable to not worry about that difference for now.)*

Comment: Yes, what I'm asking is indeed about the race condition.  If I call the WaitAny() in a recursive function, would I be able to capture all the indexes of tasks that completed, even if one task completes, and then before the call to WaitAny() returns, one or more other tasks also complete? Thus, subsequent WaitAny() calls will also get those tasks that completed before the previous WaitAny() returned?

Comment: @ptn: Sorry, I don't fully understand your question. First, I don't know what _"a recursive function"_ has to do with it. I wouldn't use recursion to iterate over an array, or to repeat calls to `WaitAny()`, and I don't see what otherwise the recursive nature of a method would have to do with the question at hand. As for how `WaitAny()` works, you can't do anything in a thread that's called `WaitAny()` before that method returns; the thread is _blocked_ at the call to `WaitAny()`. ...

Comment: ... Other than that, yes...you can check the whole array you passed to `WaitAny()` to find all the tasks that have completed by the time you check, and then call `WaitAny()` again with the remaining uncompleted tasks.

Comment: @ptn: Note that **1)** you may find a `List<T>` more convenient than an array for this purpose, and **2)** the remaining tasks continue to run after `WaitAny()` returns, so even after you scan the input once to see which tasks have completed, yet another task might complete before you get to call `WaitAny()`. Don't worry about that...just process the completed tasks you can know about immediately after, and trust that you can get the others later.

Comment: I mentioned the recursive function because I was thinking of using it to repeat calls to WaitAny(). Looks like I would have to iterate through the array after each WaitAny() call to make sure I capture other tasks that may have finished in between each WaitAny() call. I'll explore the WhenAny() option. Thank you for the explanation on that above.

Comment: @ptn: _"I mentioned the recursive function because I was thinking of using it to repeat calls to WaitAny()"_ -- I would not use recursion for that. A simple `while` loop should suffice. _"Looks like I would have to iterate through the array after each WaitAny() call to make sure I capture other tasks that may have finished in between each WaitAny() call. I'll explore the WhenAny() option."_ -- to be clear, you don't _have_ to iterate through the array. It's just the fastest way to get all the completed tasks. You can remove one task per completed call to `WaitAny()` and that would work too.

Answer (score 3):

Any task can finish at any time. Sure it is possible that two ore more tasks finished at the same time.

But there is nothing you should care about in your case. `Task.WhenAny` will return the index of one task in the array that is completed. Place a new task at the index and call `Task.WhenAny` again. If there were any completed tasks in the array it will return without a delay with the index of one of the completed tasks.

```
async Task Execute( IEnumerable<Func<Task>> taskFunctions, int maxParallel )
{
    var taskList = new List<Task>(maxParallel);
    foreach ( var taskFunc in taskFunctions )
    {
        var task = taskFunc();
        taskList.Add( task );
        if ( taskList.Count == maxParallel )
        {
            var idx = await Task.WhenAny( taskList ).ConfigureAwait(false);
            taskList.RemoveAt( idx );
        }
    }
    await Task.WhenAll( taskList ).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Does Task.WhenAny block the parent thread until a task completes in the array?

Comment: No, the `WhenAny()` method does not block the thread. It is a serious error to claim that it does.

Comment: In the code sample that Sir Rufo posted, if there were no tasks in the taskList that completed at the time the Task.WhenAny() is called, what is returned in the idx if it does not block the thread from continuing on to execute the subsequent code taskList.RemoveAt(idx)? I may be mis-understanding how the WhenAny() method works and apologize if this question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Does the "await" key word tell the thread to wait until at least one task completes before executing the code that removes the idx from the taskList?

Comment: @ptn: _"what is returned in the idx if it does not block the thread from continuing on to execute the subsequent code"_ -- you have confused "block the thread" with "continuing on to execute the subsequent code". The `WhenAny()` method is different from `WaitAny()` in that it doesn't return the result, but a `Task` that promises that a result will be available in the future. By `await`-ing that `Task`, the current method _returns_. The "subsequent code" is not executed until later, when the `Task` has completed and the result is available; but until that time, the thread _also_ is not blocked.

Comment: @ptn: _"Does the "await" key word tell the thread to wait until at least one task completes before executing the code that removes the idx from the taskList?"_ -- essentially, yes. But it is very important to understand that this "wait" doesn't happen by blocking the thread. It happens by returning control to the caller of the method and letting the thread continue to work, without executing the later code that removes the `idx` value. The method is resumed at a later time, when the wait completes and the value is available.

Comment: I was confusing the thread with a task. I see now that the code "async Task Execute" creates another task that completes when all the tasks in taskList completes and the WhenAny() is called within the Task process not the parent calling thread. So the blocking occurs within the task that manages the taskList but not the parent calling thread.